# ng-click for checkbox not working on load ,its working on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

Checkbox not working on loading the file but,its working after page refresh

My `template`:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="farmCat" class="farmCatCrop" ng-click="valueChangedTwo()"> Crop </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="farmLive" class="farmCatLiveStock" ng-click="valueChangedTwo()"> Live Stock </label>
</div>
```

Cash



livestock

My `method`:

```
$scope.valueChangedTwo = function() {
    if ($('.farmCatCrop').is(":checked"))
        $("#cash").show();
    else
        $("#cash").hide();

    if ($('.farmCatLiveStock').is(":checked"))
        $("#liveField").show();
    else
        $("#liveField").hide();
};
```

Comment: Can you add proper code above? And Why you want to use `jQuery` here, you can do by using angularJs.

Comment: Not able to see element which having `id="cash"` and `ng-model` in input element.

Comment: can we trigger ng-click without using ng-model?

Comment: Stop mixing jQuery and Angular  - come on. I'm sure if used `ngModels` on the checkboxes this problem wouldn't be happening. You don't even need any JS code for this to work - just `ngShow` with `$scope` variables being toggled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="farmCat" class="farmCatCrop" ng-model="cat.crop">Crop </label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="farmLive" class="farmCatLiveStock" ng-model="cat.livestock">Live Stock </label>
</div>
```

Then ...

```
<div id="cash" ng-show="cat.crop">Cash</div>
<div id="liveField" ng-show="cat.livestock">Live Stock</div>
```

You won't be needing jQuery since angularjs can do it better.